# Use subprocess in python to echo a variable

Tags: linux, shell, python, echo

I have a variable in python, and I'm trying to open a subprocess and echo the variable, then create a file with the variable in it.
I tried this:

```
subprocess.Popen(['echo "$var" > file.txt'], shell=True)
```

It creates the file, but it's empty. How can I get the result that I want?

Comment: Not sure of your use case, but it might be easier and more robust to open the file, format the variable appropriately into a string, and write the string to the file.

Comment: Is `var` a Python variable or a shell variable?

Comment: It's a python variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python you don't use `$` sign to use a variable. Also when you want to embed variable into string, you cannot just simply use variable name in string. You should do something like that:

```
subprocess.Popen(['echo "{}" > file.txt'.format(var)], shell=True)
```

[This](https://pyformat.info/) is great website which will explain you how to use `.format` method.